# Java: custom-exception-error

Tags: java, error-handling, custom-errors

```
$ javac TestExceptions.java 
TestExceptions.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class test
location: class TestExceptions
            throw new TestExceptions.test("If you see me, exceptions work!");
                                    ^
1 error
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestExceptions {
    static void test(String message) throws java.lang.Error{
        System.out.println(message);
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
             // Why does it not access TestExceptions.test-method in the class?
            throw new TestExceptions.test("If you see me, exceptions work!");
        }catch(java.lang.Error a){
            System.out.println("Working Status: " + a.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working Code**

Try this:

```
public class TestExceptions extends Exception {
    public TestExceptions( String s ) {
      super(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TestExceptions{
        try {
            throw new TestExceptions("If you see me, exceptions work!");
        }
        catch( Exception a ) {
            System.out.println("Working Status: " + a.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

**Problems**

There are a number of issues with the code you posted, including:

- Catching `Error` instead of `Exception`
- Using a static method to construct the exception
- Not extending `Exception` for your exception
- Not calling the superclass constructor of `Exception` with the message

The posted code resolves those issues and displays what you were expecting.

Answer (score 6):

`TestExceptions.test` returns type `void`, so you cannot `throw` it.  For this to work, it needs to return an object of a type that extends `Throwable`.

One example might be:

```
   static Exception test(String message) {
        return new Exception(message);
    }
```

However, this isn't very clean.  A better pattern would be to define a `TestException` class that extends `Exception` or `RuntimeException` or `Throwable`, and then just `throw` that.

```
class TestException extends Exception {
   public TestException(String message) {
     super(message);
   }
}

// somewhere else
public static void main(String[] args) throws TestException{
    try {
        throw new TestException("If you see me, exceptions work!");
    }catch(Exception a){
        System.out.println("Working Status: " + a.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

(Also note that all classes in package `java.lang` can be referenced by their class name rather than their fully-qualified name.  That is, you don't need to write `java.lang`.)

Comment: That's because `String` is not `Throwable`.  See the second sentence of my answer.